# How to customize just the first line of a multicolumn ListView in a fragment?

Tags: android, listview, header, fragment, multiple-columns

I created a Fragment with a multicolumn (4 columns) ListView whose entries are generated with a while on an SQLite query. Now i want to add a title for every column, like a table. How to do that?

Here is the XML related to the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the XML layout for rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FirstText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/column1"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SecondText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/column2"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ThirdText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/column3"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FourthText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/column4"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have this output:

[image]

Now i want to add a row above this table with fields like "Product", "Manufacturer", "Price" and so on... but i want to show it with a different style, for example bold or capital. How to do that?

Comment: How are you defining your columns? IOW, what is your row layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `<include>` the same row layout above your `ListView`, setting the text in the `TextView` widgets, and updating them to be bold in Java.

Or, you could create a similar horizontal `LinearLayout` and set of `TextView` widgets directly in your `ListView` layout, where you set the `TextView` widgets to be bold and provide their text captions. You might then consider moving your `android:layout_weight` attribute values to integer resources, so you define them only in one place.

There are probably other variations on the theme as well.

Comment: I added <include layout="@layout/header" /> before <ListView> but it make listview not to show... why?

Comment: I also tried the second solution (maybe better than the firt one) but happens the same: when i run the app the ListView is not showed, i see only the captions now. Here is how i edit the first XML file: http://pastebin.com/fUiZdu8Q

Comment: @smartmouse: "why?" -- you have the height set to `fill_parent`. A `ListView` row should be `wrap_content`.

Comment: This does the trick! Thank you so much and sorry if i forgot that setting :)

Comment: About android:layout_weight, i do not understand what you mean. If you can, please explain it through an example. Thank you in advance.